# Dynamically loading DbSet to DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

How do I dynamically load into an EF7 `DbContext` a X number of classes without explicitly writing them in a `DbContext` class ?

For example, I tried to avoid it like this:

```
public class MyDbContextClass : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> categories {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Product> products {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

So it could be great to load Category and Product dynamically (without knowing if I have 2 or 20 classes).

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have your entities/classes all together in one assembly?

Comment: `context.Set<YourType>()`?

Comment: Even if it is possible it isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

You should use this method:

- All entities must inherit from BaseType...

  ```
  public static void RegisterAllEntities<BaseType>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, params Assembly[] assemblies)
  {
      var types = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetExportedTypes())
                            .Where(c => c.IsClass && !c.IsAbstract && c.IsPublic && typeof(BaseType).IsAssignableFrom(c));

      foreach (var type in types)
          modelBuilder.Entity(type);
  }
  ```

Comment: altho this does do something.... i really doubt anyone would want this... as its has 0 benefits but  i see what you did there ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`dbContext.Set<T>()` creates an instance of `DbSet<T>`  as long as `T` is a type in your model (i.e. you have to add the entity type in `OnModelCreating`).

See the [source code for `.Set<T>`.](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/DbContext.cs#L785-L799)